# Why isn't ChartJS loading in my Android app?

Tags: javascript, html, chart.js

I'm trying to embed a chart locally within an Android app sing Chart.js. The code renders fine at localhost, but I can't get it to work with cdn cloudflare  or offline.

As per the documentation: I used `npm install` to download the library and copied ".\node_modules\chart.js\dist\chart.umd.js" to the local asset folder in my application. Text displays fine but the chart doesn't appear. The code relating to Chart.JS is also greyed out in the AndroidStudio editor - what am I doing wrong?

Thanks

```
 <script src="..\chart.umd.js"></script>

<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <title>Chart.js example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
       <h5>Chart JS Test</h5>
    <div class="chartBox">
      <canvas id = "myChart" width="400"></canvas>
    </div>
    <div class="chartBox">
      <canvas id = "myChart1" width="400" height="100"></canvas>
    </div>
  
    <script type="module" src="mychart.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>

<script>
```

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Why is your call to chart.js _above_ the doctype?

Comment: Yes, it's invalid HTML to have content or assets outside the head or body elements.

Comment: You may also have your path defined incorrectly `"../chart.umd.js"` rather than `"..\chart.umd.js"` (backslash vs forward slash). Look in your network tab to see if the resource is being loaded correctly.

Comment: but the script is run from inside the body so it shouldn't make a difference? Enclosing the whole block within /body / html doesn't make any difference. Based on the above directory structure, would path be better defined as ".chart.umd.js" ?